# Angular Router and Back Button

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular2-routing, back-button

I have an Angular 4 app with navigation using the Router from @angular/router

The navigation structure is fairly simple, consisting of:

```
/products
/products/:productId
/products/:productId/edit-details
/products/:productId/edit-images
etc
```

This is all working fine with the Router Module.

The problem I get is with the Browser Back button after saving data - given the following scenario:

1. User is on "/products/5" screen
2. User goes to "/products/5/edit-details" screen
3. User makes changes and clicks "Save"
4. App Saves data and navigates user back to "/products/5" screen

After doing the above User clicks Browser Back button. I think most users would expect the Back button to take them up a level to the "Product List" but it will actually take them Back to the "/products/5/edit-details" screen as that is the last route they were on.

This is probably a bit of a conflict between expected behaviour in a Website vs Single Page Application. The look and feel within a SPA is more like an App than a traditional website. In most apps the device back button works as an "Up/Back" button (e.g. on my phone using the Contacts App you get: Contacts List -> Contact Details -> Edit Contact -> Save [takes you to contact details] -> Press Back Button takes the user up to the Contacts List not back to the Edit Contact screen. So the user has been educated to expect this behaviour from the back button on their device.

I've experimented with using:

```
this.location.back();
```

instead of

```
this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

After the user clicks save

Which does partially achieve what I want but this then leaves an unwanted option for the "Forward" button - it also seems a bit wrong to be bypassing the Router module.

This behaviour is especially annoying after a Delete:
e.g. If you go to "/products/:productId/edit-images/:imageId" and delete the image then the non-existent route remains in the Back history

I've also tried using "skipLocationChange" but that doesn't seen to achieve the desired effect as if I use skipLocationChange in the Link to get to the "edit-details" screen and the user then presses the back button then bypass the :productId screen and go straight to the "/products" List

Any suggestions?

Comment: *I think most users would expect the Back button to take them up a level to the "Product List"*: no. The previous page was the product edition page, and it's the normal and expected behavior of the back button to go to the previous page. There's nothing wrong here. But nothing prevents you from adding a "Go to the product list" link in the product detail page.

Comment: @ElGringo Did you ever manage to figure it out?